# Unable to play .m3u8 file in Safari (MAC OS)

Tags: html, safari, http-live-streaming

We obtain a media stream from the server. One of the ways to play this media stream in the client's web browser is to use HLS. We segmented the media stream into multiple .ts files and created a playlist (.m3u8). But when we try to play the .m3u8 file in Safari browser, we are unable to play the video files (.ts files).

It would be very helpful if anyone can let us know how to play the .m3u8 file in Safari. We tried with the sample .m3u8 file available from Apple site and that plays properly. When we replace the .m3u8 file with our own .m3u8 file, we are unable to play the media file.

Is it required to have HTTP server to play HLS streams in  tag in Safari?

Comment: What encoding are you using for the video that's inside the ts container?

Answer (score 3):

```
Is it required to have HTTP server to play HLS streams in tag in Safari?
```

Yes, HLS (Http Live Streaming) requires the video to be served over HTTP. This means that you can't simply point your video tag to a local `.m3u8`, but rather, you must point it to an `.m3u8` file that is being served over HTTP.

Comment: And don't forget that it's possible to run a webserver on localhost.

Comment: I point it to http://127.0.0.1/~administrator/Job.m3u8 and Safari just downloads the file. What to do to play it? Media Stream Validator from Apple successfully verifies the playlist, no errors.